# Is there a way to upload large files reliable using JSF2.2

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I have a problem to upload large files to my server application (Tomcat7, JSF2.2, PrimeFaces). I would like to upload files up to 5 GB. This needs much time and the probability of a short connection lost is very high.

Currently I tried the primefaces fileupload. This works but if I lost the network connection then the upload stopped directly without any feedback on client or server side.

Is there a way to make it reliable?

Also the possibility to resume a file upload would be very fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer my question...

The best way to make an upload reliable and resumable into a JSF/Primefaces web application is the integration of the Javascript library **resumable.js** (or similar libaries based on it).

It uses the HTML5 File API which is supported by many modern browsers.

Integration/Implementation:

On client-side you have to integrate the `resumable.js` library and some Javascript code to handle the upload. For that the `resumable.js` library provide some events like uploadStart, fileSuccess and many more.
In combination with the PrimeFaces `<p:remoteCommand>` you can communicate from Javascript to the server-side web application.

*Code Example: Add resumable.js JavaScript library*

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="resumable.js" />
```

*Code Example: Initialize resumable object*

```
var r;
var maxFileSize = #{uploadDataBean.getUploadSizeLimit()};
var allowedFileExtensions = #{uploadDataBean.getFileTypes()};

function pageLoaded() {
    PF('wVarStartBtn').disable();

    r = new Resumable({
        target: '../upload',
        chunkSize: 1*1024*1024,
        forceChunkSize: true,
        prioritizeFirstAndLastChunk: false,
        simultaneousUploads: 3,
        testChunks: true,
        chunkRetryInterval: 1000,
        maxFiles: 1,
        maxFilesErrorCallback: callbackMaxFiles,
        maxFileSize: maxFileSize,
        maxFileSizeErrorCallback: callbackMaxFileSize,
        fileType: allowedFileExtensions,
        fileTypeErrorCallback: callbackFileType,
        method: "octet"
    });

    r.assignDrop($('.resumable-drop')[0]);
    r.assignBrowse($('.resumable-select')[0]);

    // ### resumable event functions ###
    r.on('fileAdded', function(file) {
        console.log("File added: Name = " + file.fileName + ", No. of Chunks = " + file.chunks.length);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

*Code Example: Communication from Javascript to the Managed Bean*

```
<h:form id="hiddenInputsForm" prependId="false" style="display:none;">
    <p:remoteCommand name="rcStartUpload" update=":msg :msgs" actionListener="#{uploadDataBean.uploadStarted()}" />
    <p:remoteCommand name="rcUploadComplete" update=":msg :msgs" actionListener="#{uploadDataBean.uploadComplete()}" />
    <p:remoteCommand name="rcAddFile" update="hiddenInputsForm" />
    <h:inputText id="fileupload-hidden-input-filename" value="#{uploadDataBean.fileName}" />
    <h:inputText id="fileupload-hidden-input-fileidentifer" value="#{uploadDataBean.fileIdentifier}" />
    <h:inputText id="fileupload-hidden-input-filesize" value="#{uploadDataBean.fileSize}" />
    <h:inputText id="fileupload-hidden-input-chunksize" value="#{uploadDataBean.chunkSize}" />
</h:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    ...

    function pageLoaded() {
        ...        
        // ### resumable event functions ###
        r.on('fileAdded', function(file) {
            console.log("File added: Name = " + file.fileName + ", No. of Chunks = " + file.chunks.length);

            document.getElementById('fileupload-hidden-input-filename').value = file.fileName;
            document.getElementById('fileupload-hidden-input-fileidentifer').value = file.uniqueIdentifier;
            document.getElementById('fileupload-hidden-input-filesize').value = file.size;
            document.getElementById('fileupload-hidden-input-chunksize').value = file.chunks.length;

            rcAddFile();

        });
        r.on('uploadStart', function () {
            console.log("Upload started");
            rcStartUpload();
        })
        r.on('fileSuccess', function(file) {
            console.log("File upload success");
            rcUploadComplete();
        });
        ...
    }

</script>
```

The server-side needs a WebFilter to receive the GET and POST requests from resumable.js. You have to implement the `doFilter` method from `javax.servlet.Filter` interface.
This filter class uses another class (e.g. UploadFileManager) with static methods to check if a chunk already received and to save nonexistent chunks.
If the upload is complete, then the client can call their managed bean via a RemoteCommand. The Bean itself can access the uploaded file by the same UploadFileManager class via a static method.

*Note:* The UploadFileManager class with the static methods must be threadsafe!

[Component diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0eTx.png)

Comment: please show the code for this to: _" In combination with the PrimeFaces RemoteCommand you can communicate from Javascript to the server-site web application."_

Comment: @Kukeltje: I have added a code snippet in the comment above.